# Исключение NullReferenceException при получении строки подключения к БД

Tags: c#

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in Lesson1.exe
>   Additional information: Ссылка на объект не
>   указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Почему я получаю данное исключение?

Пример кода:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var context = new TestDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    var roles = context.Roles.ToList();
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", role.Code, role.Name);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Исключение вылетает в этом месте:

```
TestDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

пример `app.conf`:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=WEBBD\test;Initial Catalog=Web;User ID=test;Password=1234"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Покажу наглядно что происходит, и что у меня не получается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что я не так сделал ?

Comment: Откуда у вас взялся файл `app.conf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Непосредственная причина исключения - `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]` вернул null. А это означает, что строка подключения с указанным именем не найдена.

---

А не найдена она вот почему.

Обработчик секции `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` работает с главным файлом конфигурации вашего приложения, который имеет имя `"{имя вашего главного модуля}.exe.config"` и который генерируется во время сборки исходя из файла `app.config` в вашем проекте.

Если вы назвали свой файл `app.conf` - к нему нельзя получить доступ через упрощенный API конфигурации.

Comment: Выше приложил скрины проекта и что не получается, спасибо за ответ, и помощь

Comment: @Ethernets у вас два файла с одним именем... Дальше говорить или сами?

Comment: Да если можно, я переименовал 1 файл App.config на te.config который находится в Consoles, и ничего не изменилось так же получаю исключение, или мы говорим о разных файлах ??

Comment: @Ethernets вы глупость сделали, попробуйте что-нибудь еще

Comment: извините пожалуйста а о каком хотябы файле речь идет ? я просто не вижу совпадения имен, спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets вы его уже нашли. Просто исправили неправильно.

Comment: а как правильно ?

Comment: @Ethernets подумайте. Я вам уже сказал все части отгадки, надо лишь сложить.

Comment: Хорошо, почему не подходит переименование в явном виде ? ведь файл который находится в Consoles пустой и не имеет не каких параметров, мне что там нужно написать ` <connectionStrings>
        <add name="test" </connectionStrings>`  ?

Comment: Удалил один из файлов, не помогло ... также исключение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46355/discussion-between-ethernets-and-pavel-mayorov).